Ways to Create fixed + Dynamic URL with Elementor Shortcode or URL element
I'd like to know how may I create URLs using the MAIN URL WEBSITE (home URL) on it. For example:
https://safeweb.norton.com/report?url=\[home_url\]
I need it, for the purpose of when I migrate from subdomain (which I'm using for developing option) to the production environment (it will not be the sub-domain), so that if one day the URL changes, it's not necessary to update every link manually.
Like this:
Screenshot for example of what I meant
I've tried with:
https://safeweb.norton.com/report?url={$home_url}
https://safeweb.norton.com/report?url={home_url}
https://safeweb.norton.com/report?url={{home_url}``}
https://safeweb.norton.com/report?url=\[home_url\]
https://safeweb.norton.com/report?url=$home_url
But none of them worked. I tried with either SHORTCODE on IMAGE ELEMENT (on the link field) and also with directly URL input on this link field

To create a fixed + dynamic URL in Elementor, try these methods:
Dynamic Tags in URL Fields: Use a static URL, then add a Dynamic Tag (e.g., https://yoursite.com/profile/ + User Info > Username). This lets Elementor pull user-specific data directly.
Custom Shortcode: Add a shortcode in your theme’s functions.php:
   function custom_url_shortcode() {
    $username = wp_get_current_user()->user_login;
    return "https://yoursite.com/profile/" . $username;
}
add_shortcode('custom_url', 'custom_url_shortcode');

Use [custom_url] in Elementor’s Shortcode widget.
Query Parameters: Add query strings in a URL field, e.g., https://yoursite.com/product/?id=[Dynamic Tag: Post ID].

This is what I did, but I'd like to do it without editing any PHP file. directly into LINK field of the element. example: Drag and drop an IMAGE to a container. then you go to Link URL field of this image, then do something about http://google.com/?url="+[myDomain]", not necessarily creating shortcodes in php file. this way worked, but it's not pratical.

Have you tried to use dynamic values provided by elementor ?

Muhammad Masem, not yet. I will see about it.

But for Dynamic TAG, just do like you said: http://google.com/url=[Dynamic Tag: XXX]
what do I write on "Dynamic Tag: XXX", what would it be the XXX value, once I need my domain URL?
I didn't find any tag for the current URL of the site, only home_url, but as a shortcode, not Dinamyc URL. And do I need to write: "Dinamyc Tag:" before?
